# npm install -g fibers fails on Azure Web App

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, node-gyp, node-fibers

Using the console on https://portal.azure.com/

```
> npm install -g fibers
D:\home\site\wwwroot\programs\server
gypBuild failed

npm ERR! fibers@1.0.5 install: `node ./build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the fibers@1.0.5 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the fibers package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./build.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls fibers
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "node" "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\npm\\1.4.28\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "fibers"
npm ERR! cwd D:\home\site\wwwroot\programs\server
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.32
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm


> curl -O http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.4/node.exe
D:\home\site\wwwroot
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0 9168k    0 16978    0     0  24713      0  0:06:19 --:--:--  0:06:19 25264
  4 9168k    4  433k    0     0   259k      0  0:00:35  0:00:01  0:00:34  261k
 19 9168k   19 1769k    0     0   658k      0  0:00:13  0:00:02  0:00:11  662k
 45 9168k   45 4208k    0     0  1145k      0  0:00:08  0:00:03  0:00:05 1150k
100 9168k  100 9168k    0     0  1975k      0  0:00:04  0:00:04 --:--:-- 1982k


> npm install -g fibers
D:\home\site\wwwroot
gypBuild failed

npm ERR! fibers@1.0.5 install: `node ./build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the fibers@1.0.5 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the fibers package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./build.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls fibers
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "node" "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\npm\\1.4.28\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "fibers"
npm ERR! cwd D:\home\site\wwwroot
npm ERR! node -v v0.12.4
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! not ok code 0


> npm install -g fibers@1.0.4
D:\home\site\wwwroot
gypBuild failed

npm ERR! fibers@1.0.4 install: `node ./build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the fibers@1.0.4 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the fibers package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./build.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls fibers
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "node" "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\npm\\1.4.28\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "fibers@1.0.4"
npm ERR! cwd D:\home\site\wwwroot
npm ERR! node -v v0.12.4
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! not ok code 0


> npm -g install npm@latest
D:\home\site\wwwroot
D:\local\AppData\npm\npm -> D:\local\AppData\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
npm@2.11.1 D:\local\AppData\npm\node_modules\npm


> D:\local\AppData\npm\npm -v
D:\home\site\wwwroot
2.11.1


> D:\local\AppData\npm\npm -g install fibers@latest
D:\home\site\wwwroot
npm WARN package.json WebMatrixExpressStarter@0.1.0 license should be a valid SPDX license expression
gypBuild failed
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! argv "node" "D:\\local\\AppData\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "-g" "install" "fibers@latest"
npm ERR! node v0.12.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! fibers@1.0.5 install: `node ./build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the fibers@1.0.5 install script 'node ./build.js'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the fibers package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./build.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls fibers
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\home\site\wwwroot\npm-debug.log


> more D:\home\site\wwwroot\npm-debug.log
D:\home\site\wwwroot
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'node',
1 verbose cli   'D:\\local\\AppData\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   '-g',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'fibers@latest' ]
2 info using npm@2.11.1
3 info using node@v0.12.4
4 verbose install initial load of D:\home\site\wwwroot\package.json
5 warn package.json WebMatrixExpressStarter@0.1.0 license should be a valid SPDX license expression
6 verbose readDependencies loading dependencies from D:\home\site\wwwroot\package.json
7 silly cache add args [ 'fibers@latest', null ]
8 verbose cache add spec fibers@latest
9 silly cache add parsed spec { raw: 'fibers@latest',
9 silly cache add   scope: null,
9 silly cache add   name: 'fibers',
9 silly cache add   rawSpec: 'latest',
9 silly cache add   spec: 'latest',
9 silly cache add   type: 'tag' }
10 silly addNamed fibers@latest
11 verbose addNamed "latest" is being treated as a dist-tag for fibers
12 info addNameTag [ 'fibers', 'latest' ]
13 silly mapToRegistry name fibers
14 silly mapToRegistry using default registry
15 silly mapToRegistry registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
16 silly mapToRegistry uri https://registry.npmjs.org/fibers
17 verbose addNameTag registry:https://registry.npmjs.org/fibers not in flight; fetching
18 verbose request uri https://registry.npmjs.org/fibers
19 verbose request no auth needed
20 info attempt registry request try #1 at 9:12:12 AM
21 verbose request id 8e64d1a508d91843
22 verbose etag "2P564RC6MOE4HK6NYC1SR8YSK"
23 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fibers
24 http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/fibers
25 silly get cb [ 304,
25 silly get   { date: 'Thu, 11 Jun 2015 09:12:12 GMT',
25 silly get     via: '1.1 varnish',
25 silly get     'cache-control': 'max-age=60',
25 silly get     etag: '"2P564RC6MOE4HK6NYC1SR8YSK"',
25 silly get     age: '55',
25 silly get     connection: 'keep-alive',
25 silly get     'x-served-by': 'cache-lcy1135-LCY',
25 silly get     'x-cache': 'HIT',
25 silly get     'x-cache-hits': '9',
25 silly get     'x-timer': 'S1434013932.796548,VS0,VE0',
25 silly get     vary: 'Accept' } ]
26 verbose etag https://registry.npmjs.org/fibers from cache
27 verbose get saving fibers to D:\local\AppData\npm-cache\registry.npmjs.org\fibers\.cache.json
28 silly addNameTag next cb for fibers with tag latest
29 silly addNamed fibers@1.0.5
30 verbose addNamed "1.0.5" is a plain semver version for fibers
31 silly cache afterAdd fibers@1.0.5
32 verbose afterAdd D:\local\AppData\npm-cache\fibers\1.0.5\package\package.json not in flight; writing
33 verbose afterAdd D:\local\AppData\npm-cache\fibers\1.0.5\package\package.json written
34 silly install resolved [ { name: 'fibers',
34 silly install resolved     version: '1.0.5',
34 silly install resolved     description: 'Cooperative multi-tasking for Javascript',
34 silly install resolved     keywords:
34 silly install resolved      [ 'fiber',
34 silly install resolved        'fibers',
34 silly install resolved        'coroutine',
34 silly install resolved        'thread',
34 silly install resolved        'async',
34 silly install resolved        'parallel',
34 silly install resolved        'worker',
34 silly install resolved        'future',
34 silly install resolved        'promise' ],
34 silly install resolved     homepage: 'https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers',
34 silly install resolved     author:
34 silly install resolved      { name: 'Marcel Laverdet',
34 silly install resolved        email: 'marcel@laverdet.com',
34 silly install resolved        url: 'https://github.com/laverdet/' },
34 silly install resolved     main: 'fibers',
34 silly install resolved     scripts: { install: 'node ./build.js', test: 'node ./test.js' },
34 silly install resolved     repository:
34 silly install resolved      { type: 'git',
34 silly install resolved        url: 'git://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers.git' },
34 silly install resolved     engines: { node: '>=0.5.2' },
34 silly install resolved     gitHead: 'aff726a79af0c9d400ec0fa37be53f23643a4623',
34 silly install resolved     bugs: { url: 'https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers/issues' },
34 silly install resolved     _id: 'fibers@1.0.5',
34 silly install resolved     _shasum: '3bea1f697d8540bb3904961ad50939bdee1df678',
34 silly install resolved     _from: 'fibers@latest',
34 silly install resolved     _npmVersion: '1.4.28',
34 silly install resolved     _npmUser: { name: 'laverdet', email: 'marcel.npm@laverdet.com' },
34 silly install resolved     maintainers: [ [Object] ],
34 silly install resolved     dist:
34 silly install resolved      { shasum: '3bea1f697d8540bb3904961ad50939bdee1df678',
34 silly install resolved        tarball: 'http://registry.npmjs.org/fibers/-/fibers-1.0.5.tgz' },
34 silly install resolved     directories: {},
34 silly install resolved     _resolved: 'https://registry.npmjs.org/fibers/-/fibers-1.0.5.tgz',
34 silly install resolved     readme: 'ERROR: No README data found!' } ]
35 info install fibers@1.0.5 into D:\home\site\wwwroot
36 info installOne fibers@1.0.5
37 verbose installOne of fibers to D:\home\site\wwwroot not in flight; installing
38 verbose lock using D:\local\AppData\npm-cache\_locks\fibers-2f010a6cc5d6f77d.lock for D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\fibers
39 silly install write writing fibers 1.0.5 to D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\fibers
40 verbose unbuild node_modules\fibers
41 silly gentlyRm D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\fibers is being purged from base D:\home\site\wwwroot
42 verbose gentlyRm don't care about contents; nuking D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\fibers
43 verbose tar unpack D:\local\AppData\npm-cache\fibers\1.0.5\package.tgz
44 verbose tar unpacking to D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\fibers
45 silly gentlyRm D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\fibers is being purged
46 verbose gentlyRm don't care about contents; nuking D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\fibers
47 silly gunzTarPerm modes [ '777', '666' ]
48 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry package.json
49 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'package.json', 420, 438 ]
50 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry .npmignore
51 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ '.npmignore', 420, 438 ]
52 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry README.md
53 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'README.md', 420, 438 ]
54 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry LICENSE
55 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'LICENSE', 420, 438 ]
56 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry quick-test.js
57 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'quick-test.js', 420, 438 ]
58 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry future.js
59 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'future.js', 420, 438 ]
60 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry build.js
61 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'build.js', 493, 511 ]
62 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry test.js
63 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'test.js', 493, 511 ]
64 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry fibers.js
65 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'fibers.js', 420, 438 ]
66 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry binding.gyp
67 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'binding.gyp', 420, 438 ]
68 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry bin/.npmignore
69 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'bin/.npmignore', 420, 438 ]
70 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry bin/darwin-ia32-v8-3.14/fibers.node
71 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'bin/darwin-ia32-v8-3.14/fibers.node', 493, 511 ]
72 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry bin/darwin-x64-v8-3.14/fibers.node
73 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'bin/darwin-x64-v8-3.14/fibers.node', 493, 511 ]
74 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry bin/linux-ia32-v8-3.14/fibers.node
75 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'bin/linux-ia32-v8-3.14/fibers.node', 420, 438 ]
76 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry bin/linux-x64-v8-3.14/fibers.node
77 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'bin/linux-x64-v8-3.14/fibers.node', 420, 438 ]
78 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry bin/win32-ia32-v8-3.14/fibers.node
79 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'bin/win32-ia32-v8-3.14/fibers.node', 420, 438 ]
80 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry bin/win32-x64-v8-3.14/fibers.node
81 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'bin/win32-x64-v8-3.14/fibers.node', 420, 438 ]
82 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry src/coroutine.cc
83 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'src/coroutine.cc', 420, 438 ]
84 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry src/coroutine.h
85 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'src/coroutine.h', 420, 438 ]
86 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry src/fibers.cc
87 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'src/fibers.cc', 420, 438 ]
88 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry src/libcoro/README
89 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'src/libcoro/README', 420, 438 ]
90 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry src/libcoro/LICENSE
91 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'src/libcoro/LICENSE', 420, 438 ]
92 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry src/libcoro/conftest.c
93 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'src/libcoro/conftest.c', 420, 438 ]
94 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry src/libcoro/coro.c
95 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'src/libcoro/coro.c', 420, 438 ]
96 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry src/libcoro/coro.h
97 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'src/libcoro/coro.h', 420, 438 ]
98 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry test/already-running.js
99 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'test/already-running.js', 420, 438 ]
100 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry test/exit.js
101 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'test/exit.js', 420, 438 ]
102 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry test/fibonacci.js
103 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'test/fibonacci.js', 420, 438 ]
104 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry test/finish-multiple.js
105 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'test/finish-multiple.js', 420, 438 ]
106 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry test/exec.js
107 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'test/exec.js', 420, 438 ]
108 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry test/future.js
109 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'test/future.js', 420, 438 ]
110 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry test/illegal-yield.js
111 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'test/illegal-yield.js', 420, 438 ]
112 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry test/pool.js
113 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'test/pool.js', 420, 438 ]
114 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry test/process-title.js
115 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'test/process-title.js', 420, 438 ]
116 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry test/stack-overflow.js
117 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'test/stack-overflow.js', 420, 438 ]
118 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry test/current.js
119 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'test/current.js', 420, 438 ]
120 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry test/stack-overflow2.js
121 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'test/stack-overflow2.js', 420, 438 ]
122 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry test/child-process.js
123 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'test/child-process.js', 420, 438 ]
124 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry test/started.js
125 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'test/started.js', 420, 438 ]
126 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry test/bad-context.js
127 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'test/bad-context.js', 420, 438 ]
128 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry test/unwind.js
129 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'test/unwind.js', 420, 438 ]
130 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry test/future-exception.js
131 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'test/future-exception.js', 420, 438 ]
132 verbose write writing to D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\fibers\package.json
133 info preinstall fibers@1.0.5
134 verbose readDependencies loading dependencies from D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\fibers\package.json
135 verbose readDependencies loading dependencies from D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\fibers\package.json
136 silly install resolved []
137 verbose about to build D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\fibers
138 info build D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\fibers
139 info linkStuff fibers@1.0.5
140 silly linkStuff fibers@1.0.5 has D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules as its parent node_modules
141 silly linkStuff fibers@1.0.5 is part of a global install
142 silly linkStuff fibers@1.0.5 is installed into a global node_modules
143 silly linkStuff fibers@1.0.5 is installed into the top-level global node_modules
144 verbose linkBins fibers@1.0.5
145 verbose linkMans fibers@1.0.5
146 verbose rebuildBundles fibers@1.0.5
147 info install fibers@1.0.5
148 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
149 info fibers@1.0.5 Failed to exec install script
150 verbose unlock done using D:\local\AppData\npm-cache\_locks\fibers-2f010a6cc5d6f77d.lock for D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\fibers
151 verbose stack Error: fibers@1.0.5 install: `node ./build.js`
151 verbose stack Exit status 1
151 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (D:\local\AppData\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:213:16)
151 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:110:17)
151 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (D:\local\AppData\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:24:14)
151 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
151 verbose stack     at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
151 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
152 verbose pkgid fibers@1.0.5
153 verbose cwd D:\home\site\wwwroot
154 error Windows_NT 6.2.9200
155 error argv "node" "D:\\local\\AppData\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "-g" "install" "fibers@latest"
156 error node v0.12.4
157 error npm  v2.11.1
158 error code ELIFECYCLE
159 error fibers@1.0.5 install: `node ./build.js`
159 error Exit status 1
160 error Failed at the fibers@1.0.5 install script 'node ./build.js'.
160 error This is most likely a problem with the fibers package,
160 error not with npm itself.
160 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
160 error     node ./build.js
160 error You can get their info via:
160 error     npm owner ls fibers
160 error There is likely additional logging output above.
161 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
162 verbose unbuild node_modules\fibers
163 info preuninstall fibers@1.0.5
164 info uninstall fibers@1.0.5
165 verbose unbuild rmStuff fibers@1.0.5 from D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules
166 info postuninstall fibers@1.0.5
167 silly gentlyRm D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\fibers is being purged from base D:\home\site\wwwroot
168 verbose gentlyRm don't care about contents; nuking D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\fibers
169 silly vacuum-fs purging D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\fibers
170 silly vacuum-fs quitting because other entries in D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules


> git clone git://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers.git
D:\home\site\wwwroot
Cloning into 'node-fibers'...
Checking connectivity... done


> cd node-fibers
D:\home\site\wwwroot\node-fibers

> D:\local\AppData\npm\npm install node-gyp
D:\home\site\wwwroot\node-fibers
node-gyp@2.0.1 node_modules\node-gyp
├── osenv@0.1.1
├── rimraf@2.4.0
├── graceful-fs@3.0.8
├── nopt@3.0.2 (abbrev@1.0.7)
├── which@1.1.1 (is-absolute@0.1.7)
├── minimatch@1.0.0 (sigmund@1.0.1, lru-cache@2.6.4)
├── semver@4.3.6
├── fstream@1.0.6 (inherits@2.0.1)
├── mkdirp@0.5.1 (minimist@0.0.8)
├── path-array@1.0.0 (array-index@0.1.1)
├── tar@1.0.3 (inherits@2.0.1, block-stream@0.0.8)
├── glob@4.5.3 (inherits@2.0.1, inflight@1.0.4, once@1.3.2, minimatch@2.0.8)
├── npmlog@1.2.1 (ansi@0.3.0, gauge@1.2.0, are-we-there-yet@1.0.4)
└── request@2.57.0 (caseless@0.10.0, forever-agent@0.6.1, aws-sign2@0.5.0, stringstream@0.0.4, tunnel-agent@0.4.0, isstream@0.1.2, json-stringify-safe@5.0.1, oauth-sign@0.8.0, combined-stream@1.0.3, node-uuid@1.4.3, qs@3.1.0, mime-types@2.0.14, form-data@0.2.0, http-signature@0.11.0, bl@0.9.4, tough-cookie@2.0.0, hawk@2.3.1, har-validator@1.7.1)


> ..\node node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild
D:\home\site\wwwroot\node-fibers
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@2.0.1
gyp info using node@0.12.4 | win32 | ia32
gyp http GET http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.4/node-v0.12.4.tar.gz
gyp http 200 http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.4/node-v0.12.4.tar.gz
gyp http GET http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.4/SHASUMS256.txt
gyp http GET http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.4/node.lib
gyp http GET http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.4/x64/node.lib
gyp http 200 http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.4/SHASUMS256.txt
gyp http 200 http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.4/node.lib
gyp http 200 http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.4/x64/node.lib
gyp info spawn python
gyp info spawn args [ 'D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\node-fibers\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
gyp info spawn args   '-G',
gyp info spawn args   'msvs_version=auto',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\node-fibers\\build\\config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\node-fibers\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'D:\\home\\.node-gyp\\0.12.4\\common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=D:\\home\\.node-gyp\\0.12.4',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\node-fibers',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\node-fibers\\build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
gyp info spawn msbuild
gyp info spawn args [ 'build/binding.sln',
gyp info spawn args   '/clp:Verbosity=minimal',
gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=Win32' ]
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `msbuild` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node-fibers\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
gyp ERR! command "..\\node" "D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\node-fibers\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\home\site\wwwroot\node-fibers
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok 


>
```

How can I fix this? Is this all the error info there is?

Answer (score 0):

[Issue 222](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers/issues/222) seems like I have to wait for binaries.